# excel vba sorting int values on list view

Tags: excel, vba

i need to sort my values by their int values for example
1
2
3
10
1000

but my code works like string like this
1
10
100
2
3

here is my sorting code for EXCEL VBA :

```
Private Sub lstview1_ColumnClick(ByVal ColumnHeader As MSComctlLib.ColumnHeader)


With lstview1
    .SortKey = ColumnHeader.Index - 1
    If .SortOrder = lvwAscending Then
        .SortOrder = lvwDescending
    Else
        .SortOrder = lvwAscending
    End If
    .Sorted = True
End With
```

End Sub

how can i fix this for excel vba

Comment: I suppose you must convert, before sort, your data as Integer. Your sort is alphabetical

Comment: i know that but i dont know how to convert a listview value :/

Comment: See here: https://codekabinett.com/rdumps.php?Lang=2&targetDoc=logical-numerals-sorting-access-vba

Answer (score 4):

The Listview sorts alphabetically and that is one of it's limitations. Here is a quick example that I created for you to sort numeric data.

**Code**

```
Option Explicit

Dim i As Long

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    With ListView1
        .View = lvwReport
        
        .ColumnHeaders.Add , , "Number", 50
        .ColumnHeaders.Add , , "Fruit", 50
        
        For i = 1000 To 1 Step -1
            .ListItems.Add(, , i).SubItems(1) = "Fruit" & i
        Next
    End With
End Sub

Private Sub ListView1_ColumnClick(ByVal ColumnHeader As MSComctlLib.ColumnHeader)
    With ListView1
        If ColumnHeader.Index = 1 Then
            SortDataWithNumbers
        Else
            .Sorted = True
        End If
    End With
End Sub

Sub SortDataWithNumbers()
    Dim sTemp As String * 10
    Dim lvCount As Long
    
    With ListView1
        lvCount = .ListItems.Count
        
        For i = 1 To lvCount
            sTemp = vbNullString
            
            If .SortKey Then
                'RSet - right align a string within a string variable.
                RSet sTemp = .ListItems(i).SubItems(.SortKey)
                .ListItems(i).SubItems(.SortKey) = sTemp
            Else
                RSet sTemp = .ListItems(i)
                .ListItems(i).Text = sTemp
            End If
        Next
        
        .Sorted = True
        
        For i = 1 To lvCount
            If .SortKey Then
                .ListItems(i).SubItems(.SortKey) = _
                LTrim$(.ListItems(i).SubItems(.SortKey))
            Else
                .ListItems(i).Text = LTrim$(.ListItems(i))
            End If
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

**In Action**

[image]

Comment: Wow you are amazing !

Comment: Super! I never used `RSet` and I didn't even know about its existence. I was thinking of loading the listView into an array, sort it after converting to `Long` and reload the sorted array... Voted up with joy!

Answer (score 1):

Siddharth Rout code works great, but if you want to be able to sort all columns and some of them are numeric, you can use ColumnHeader.Index, and with the following code (source and credits: https://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=578008):

```
Private Sub ListView1_ColumnClick(ByVal ColumnHeader As MSComctlLib.ColumnHeader)
With ListView1
    .Sorted = False
    If .SortKey <> ColumnHeader.Index - 1 Then
        .SortKey = ColumnHeader.Index - 1
    Else
        .SortOrder = 1 - .SortOrder
    End If
    
    'In the following line you specify the columns with numeric values
    If ColumnHeader.Index = 1 Or ColumnHeader.Index = 7 Then 
        Dim S As String * 10, N As Integer
        'justify the text using padding spaces
        For N = 1 To .ListItems.Count
            S = vbNullString
            If .SortKey Then
                RSet S = .ListItems(N).SubItems(.SortKey)
                .ListItems(N).SubItems(.SortKey) = S
            Else
                RSet S = .ListItems(N)
                .ListItems(N).Text = S
            End If
        Next
        'sort column using "justified" text
        .Sorted = True
        'trim spaces from the text
        For N = 1 To .ListItems.Count
            If .SortKey Then
                .ListItems(N).SubItems(.SortKey) = _
                LTrim$(.ListItems(N).SubItems(.SortKey))
            Else
                .ListItems(N).Text = LTrim$(.ListItems(N))
            End If
        Next
    Else
        .Sorted = True
    End If
End With
End Sub
```